# Overloading and wrapping method of field of parent class in python

Tags: python, overloading, wrapper

For example I have something like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def foo(self, a, b, c):
        return a + b + c


class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = A()


def wrapper_func(func):

    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return func(self, a=3, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @wrapper_func
    def ???
```

Is it possible to some how overload and then wrap method `foo` of the field of parent `B` class in python without inherits from class `A`? I need the wrapper indeed because I have the different methods with same arguments, but in the same time I have to save original class B methods native (besides overloading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `C`'s parent class using `super` and then pass all the parameters to the `foo` method of the composed class instance `A()` via the *inherited* attribute `b` of the class `C`:

```
def wrapper_func(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['a'] = 3
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()

    @wrapper_func
    def bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.b.foo(*args, **kwargs) # access foo via attribute b
```

*Trial:*

```
c = C()
print(c.bar(a=1, b=2, c=3))
# 8  -> 3+2+3
```

---

To make the call to the decorated function via `c.b.foo`, *patch* the `c.b.foo` method with the new `bar` method:

```
class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()
        self._b_foo = self.b.foo
        self.b.foo = self.bar

    @wrapper_func
    def bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._b_foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

*Trial:*

```
c = C()
print(c.b.foo(a=1, b=2, c=3))
# 8  -> 3+2+3
```

Comment: So that way calling of wrapped method will be like that `c.bar(1, 2, 3)`, but I need the same calling name such as `c.b.foo(1, 2, 3)` to be. But I guess this is not possible...?

Comment: Why `c.b.foo(1, 2, 3)`? That will only call the `foo` method of `A`

Comment: Yep, basically this will call the `foo` method of `A`, but I mean overloading and wrapping like `def b.foo(self): ...`, for calling the same `c.b.foo()` instead of  another name like `c.bar()`. And this is not possible I guess?